# Modifying Arduino code to read serial to control shift register

Tags: c, arduino, midi

I am needing to send a [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI) signal through the [midi2serial converter](http://spikenzielabs.com/SpikenzieLabs/Serial_MIDI.html).

I am using [THIS](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut) shift register, in order to control 32 individual LEDs.

How do I modify the shift register code to accept the MIDI serial signal to light specific LEDs in the matrixs?

I'm hoping to modify the code in http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShftOut12 to meet my needs.

I'm confused about a) how the MIDI signal going into the MIDI-to-serial converter looks coming out the other end. (That is, does each MIDI message turn into an array, or what?)

Each MIDI signal will be something like (144, 60, 124) and b) how do the shift register sketch respond to the MIDI signal?

I need something like:

```
if ( First bit = 144) {
    if (second bit = 60) {
        ...light LED #1...
    }
    if (second bit = 61) {
        ...light LED 2...
    }

    etc., etc.
}
```

Comment: I'm sure, I have answered a similar question from you already. Where is that question gone?

Answer (score 0):

May be try having the arduino send the raw serial data from the midi2serial to the computer, so you can check what it looks like (note it will be converted to ASCII if you use arduino serial monitor). then in the arduino use the Serial.Read command the read the serial into an array, then search through the array for 144, then use the shift register code to light(next byte value - 60).